# Troubles reverseengineering a weight scale

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, reverse-engineering

I'm starting a project of wireless body scale, so I bought a scale on Amazon to see the electronics inside.

The scale uses 4 load cells, a half-bridge, 4 metal electrodes, a Bluetooth module and a tactile module.

Unfortunately because it was a cheap scale, there is resin on one of the only chips of the board. It seems to be an all-in-one chip.

Do you have any idea what chip that can be?

I saw that a commonly used chip was the HX711, but this chip doesn't handle the metal electrodes for body composition, so I don't think that's it.

Here are the pictures of the PCB:

[image: PCB Bottom]

[image: PCB Top]

Comment: "Unfortunately even if that was a cheap scale, there is resin on one of the only chips of the board. It seems to be an all-in-one chip." I think this is backwards - because it is a cheap scale, there will only be a minimal component count, so having a blobbed chip for a mass market product is to be expected.

Comment: If you found out the chip number, what were you planning on doing?

Comment: I'd like to use the component for my project (or at least explain its function)

Comment: The sensors are reusable, the control electronics and calibration is  left as an exercise for the reader and won't be reused. It's brilliant IP protection through market barriers, but it also serves to squeeze out gross margin wherever you can. In this case 5cents in plastic packaging. This is serious engineering to design for cost and likely not the best choice for a first foray.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately even if that was a cheap scale, there is resin on one of the only chips of the board.

not *even*, but *because: packaging chips costs money. if you're producing a board in high quantities, and don't need to ever repair any of these, the direct wire bonding of silicon dies to boards is pretty common.

This is most probably an application-specific IC for scales. Scales are produced in the millions, under an extreme price pressure – thus making the design and manufacturing for an IC for this singular purpose sensible.

That design doesn't help you – you'll neither buy a wire-bonding machine nor 10000 of the scale ICs, so you probably won't even be able to buy this, even if you knew the manufacturer and type of the IC. Also, if you just want the features the all-in-one IC has, well, go buy a supermarket scale. Dropping an ASIC into the design that its manufacturer has prepared for you is... not that exciting.

So a simple microcontroller / ADC-based "bespoke" design of your own is the way to go.

Comment: I see, I thought resin was to hide the chip, but maybe if that's for protecting that makes sense.

Comment: it's for protection, but you have the wrong idea of what it is. Instead of a little square black plastic encapsulation, the chip is really just a piece of silicon die lying on the board. It's not soldered to traces, the traces are connected directly via bond wires. Without that blob of epoxy, the wires would be ripped off by anything, including an especially stiff breeze of air.

Comment: @Gauthier maybe this illustrates what the blob is: https://hackaday.com/2016/08/25/the-mystery-behind-the-globs-of-epoxy/